# Overwrite instance of BinaryWriter C#

Tags: c#, stream

I have a class that needs to keep an instance of a BinaryWriter open over several write function calls (data is packet based). It also has to create a new file once it has written a certain amount of data/packets.

Normally I would just close the Binary Writer and reinstantiate it with a new file path, but the overhead associated with that operation is too great for my application. I tried closing the writer in a seperate thread, but that interferes with the new instance I create later.

My last ditch attempt was not to close the Writer (and stream) at all, and simply create a new instance of it everytime I'd written the required packets. This seems to work, and doesn't cause any memory leaks, but I'd really like to know what goes on if you do this.

Here is my (simplified) code to illustrate:

```
class Writer
{
    BinaryWriter binWriter;
    int bytesWritten;
    int filesWritten;
    const int maxFilesize = 10E9;


    Writer(string filepath)
    {
        binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Create));
        bytesWritten = 0;
        filesWritten = 0;
    }


   WritePacket(byte[] packet)
   {
        if(bytesWritten<maxFileSize)
        {
            binWriter.Write(packet);
            bytesWritten += packet.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            // this is where I'd normally call Dispose(), but the overhead 
            // is too high, and disposing the stream in a seperate thread
            // interferes with the new one

            // what actually happens here? it's the only thing I've found to 
            //work...

            filesWritten++;
            binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filepath + filesWritten, FileMode.Create));
        }
   }
```

It feels bad, but this is the only solution that works so far. Any insight would be great!

Comment: why don't you just use the using keyword. write everything you need to write inside it and are good to go? what do you mean with "the overhead is to big" ?

Comment: The Close() or Dispose() methods take roughly 150ms to execute on my computer, time during which data accumulates in a buffer waiting to be written. Considering the fact that the Binary Writer can only just keep up with the rate at which data is arriving in the buffer, it's only a matter of time before the buffer is full and data is lost. The only way out of this is to reduce the time when the CPU is not actively writing to disk, which is when the stream is being disposed (creating a new instance of the Binary Writer takes less than a millisecond, so that's okay).

Comment: The using keyword still calls these methods, so it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: So you have an endless stream of bytes coming in and your buffer only has a pretty low size?

Comment: You could change your if condition to check if the fileSize + the newPackage will exceed your max fileSize and invoke an event. The handler of that event could then instantiate a new Writer to write the next bytes to the next file. I don't really get your problem as you are overwrite your file each time

Comment: Do your binary writes to a MemoryStream, then close and pass that stream to a separate async file writer. Disposing the binary writer should be much faster since there would be no unmanaged system resources to dispose of (filehandles, etc.). Unless your file size is large enough to make an in-memory solution untenable.

Comment: @TobiasTheel wouldn't the problem still be the same, as I'd be overwriting the same object?

Comment: @Kevin Unfortunately my file size is 1GB, so in memory solutions are untenable...